# How many words of length $n$ can we make from $0, 1, 2$ if $2$'s cannot be consecutive?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

How many words we can make from $0,1,2$? The restriction is we can't put the digit $2$ after the digit $2$.

My solution:

I tried to solve it with Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Count the number of the words without restriction and then I decreased the options that I don't want. The number of ways to make words without restriction $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot 3$, so this is $3^n$.  And then the number that I don't want to count is: 
$$\binom {n-1}{2} - \binom {n-2}{3} + \cdots + (-1)^n \cdot \frac{ (n-(n+1)}{(i+1)!}$$
so my solution is $$3^n - \sum_{i=1}^n-1 \frac{(-1)^n \cdot (n-i)}{(i+1)!}$$
This is not the answer. Can someone help me? What did I do wrong? 
Does the problem have any solution with a recurrence relation??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that pairs of consecutive $2$'s can overlap or be disjoint.  For instance, both $12220$ and $22122$ have two pairs of consecutive $2$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is best approached through a recurrence relation.

Let $a_n$ denote the number of permissible sequences of length $n$.

No sequence of length $1$ can have two consecutive $2$'s.  Since there are three ways the first position can be filled, $a_1 = 3$.

The only sequence of length $2$ that has two consecutive $2$'s is $22$.  Since each of the two positions can be filled in two ways, $a_2 = 3 \cdot 3 - 1 = 8$.

Notice that any permissible sequence of length $n$ can be extended to a sequence of length $n + 1$ by appending a $0$ or a $1$ to the end of the permissible sequence of length $n$.

We can only have a permissible sequence of length $n + 1$ that ends in a $2$ if the $n$th digit is a $0$ or a $1$.  Hence, any permissible sequence of length $n - 1$ can be extended to a permissible sequence of length $n + 1$ by appending $02$ or $12$ to the end of the permissible sequence of length $n - 1$.

Hence, we have the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_1 & = 3\\
a_2 & = 8\\
a_{n + 1} & = 2a_n + 2a_{n - 1}, n \geq 2
\end{align*}

If I am interpreting your attempt correctly, you are trying to eliminate those sequences with two or more consecutive $2$'s.  However, you have only excluded those sequences in which all the $2$'s are consecutive.  They can also appear in disjoint pairs.  For instance, both the sequences $12220$ and $22122$ have two pairs of consecutive $2$'s.  The consecutive pairs overlap in $12220$ and are disjoint in $22122$.  Trying to count pairs of consecutive $2$'s becomes trickier as $n$ increases, which is why I approached the problem through a recurrence relation.

Comment: @Servaes  I meant by appending $02$ or $12$.  Thank you for catching the error.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the recurrence relation has allows for a closed forms
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}((1+\sqrt{3})^n(2+\sqrt{3})-(1-\sqrt{3})^{n+1}(2-\sqrt{3}))=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}((2+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})^n-(5-3\sqrt{3})(1-\sqrt{3})^n).$$

Comment: @Servaes You have typos in your comment. We have $a_n=(A x^n+B y^n)/2 \sqrt 3$ where $A=\sqrt 3 +2, $ $B=\sqrt 3 -2, $  $x=1+\sqrt 3 , $ $y=1-\sqrt 3.$

Answer (score 1):

Forgive the second answer, but I can't comment on the previous answer (not yet enough reputation). The recurrence in N.F. Taussig's answer is correct (and very concisely explained!). I would add you can get a closed form, since this is a linear recurrence. In this case it's very nice (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html).

Any permissible sequence of length $n$ can be extended to a permissible sequence of length $n+1$ by appending a $0$ or a $1$ (there's the $2a_n$). A permissible sequence of length $n+1$ that ends in a $2$ must be obtained from a permissible sequence of length $n-1$ by appending either $02$ or $12$ (not $01$ or $02$, and there's the $2a_{n-1}$).

Either way, the recurrence relation is certainly $$a_{n+1}=2a_n+2a_{n-1},n\ge 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)* which is a convenient method to derive a *[generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)* for problems of this kind.

> We consider words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1,2\}$$ and the set $\mathcal{B}=\{22\}$ of *bad* words, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for.
>
> We derive a function $F(x)$ with the coefficient of $x^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.
>   According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $F(x)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and with the *weight-numerator* $\mathcal{C}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])
> \end{align*}

We calculate according to the paper
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])&=-x^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])x
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[22])=-\frac{x^2}{1+x}
\end{align*}

It follows:

> A generating function $F(x)$ for the number of words built from $\{0,1,2\}$ which do *not* contain the subword $22$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)&=\frac{1}{1-dx-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\left(1-3x+\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{1+x}{1-2x-2x^2}\\
> &=1+3x+8x^2+\color{blue}{22}x^\color{blue}{3}+60x^4+164x^5+448x^6\\
> &\qquad+1224x^7+3344x^8+9136x^9+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We see e.g. the term $22x^3$ indicates there are $\color{blue}{22}$ different words of length $\color{blue}{\text{three}}$ built from $\{0,1,2\}$ which do not contain $22$. Out of the $3^3=27$ different words of length three built from $\{0,1,2\}$ there are precisely five words
\begin{align*}
022,122,222,221,220
\end{align*}
which are to exclude, resulting in a total of $27-5=22$ words.

Using *[partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration)* we can derive a representation of $F(x)$ as *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*. From this representation we can easily obtain the coeffcients of $x^n$ which are the number of wanted words, i.e. the words which do not contain $22$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\frac{1+x}{1-2x-2x^2}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(1+\sqrt{3}x)}-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(1-\sqrt{3}x)}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1+\sqrt{3})^nx^n-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\sqrt{3})^nx^n\\
\end{align*}
and conclude:

> The number of words of length $n$ built from $\{0,1,2\}$ which do *not* contain $22$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}(1+\sqrt{3})^n-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}}(1-\sqrt{3})^n\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>   which is a sequence starting with
>   \begin{align*}
> 1,3,8,22,60,164,448,1224,3344,9136,\ldots
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with (1).

Comment: This is very nice. (+1). Good variety on the page. The reason I did it the way I did is that the OP asked for inclusion-exclusion. One could also use the DFA method here which requires just three states i.e. variables.