# Arrangements of balls from a bag

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A bag contains $2$ red, $2$ green, $2$ black, $3$ white, $1$ yellow, $1$ brown and $1$ orange ball.

In how many ways the balls be arranged in a row by taking all of them together if balls of same color cannot be placed adjacent?

I am aware that $\dfrac{12!}{2!\times 2! \times 2! \times 3!}$ arrangements are possible. But these arrangements contain balls of same colors placed adjacent also. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the balls of the same color distinguishable from each other?

Comment: balls of same color are identical.

Comment: answer is $3301200$

Comment: @Kiran Any explanation for this result ? Just posting a number doesn´t help.

Comment: @callculus, i did using a calculator. posting it now. was waiting for a shorter answer :)

Comment: @Kiran I´m looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @callculus, pl see my answer. Not exactly my answer, generated using the tool mentioned :)

Comment: @callculus, do u have a shorter way of approaching this problem?

Comment: @Kiran Not really. When I read the exercise I had the feeling that the calculations would be excessive. You have made it this way. But it is hard to comprehend. I only can hope that what you did is right.

Comment: @callculus: I've added an answer which confirms Kiran's result.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is based upon a generating function of *[generalized Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Explicit_examples_and_properties_of_the_generalized_Laguerre_polynomials)*
\begin{align*}
  L_k^{(\alpha)}(t)=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^k\binom{k+\alpha}{k-i}\frac{t^i}{i!}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

The Laguerre polynomials have some remarkable combinatorial properties and one of them is precisely suited to answer problems of this kind. This is nicely presented in *[Counting words with Laguerre series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6232v1.pdf)* by Jair Taylor.

> We encode the colors (r)ed, (g)reen, (b)lack, (w)hite, (y)ellow, (B)rown, (o)range of the balls with the letters
>   \begin{align*}
> \{r,g,b,w,y,B,o\}
> \end{align*}
>   and are looking for words of length $12$ built from
>   \begin{align*}
> r,r,g,g,b,b,w,w,w,y,B,o
> \end{align*}
>   which have the property that they contain no consecutive equal letters. These words are called **Carlitz words** or **Smirnov words**.

We find in section 2 of the referred paper Laguerre polynomials $l_k(t)$ defined by their generating function
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty l_k(t)x^k=e^{\frac{tx}{1+x}}
\end{align*}
The first few such polynomials are
\begin{align*}
l_0(t)&=1\\
l_1(t)&=t\\
l_2(t)&=\frac{1}{2}t^2-t\\
l_3(t)&=\frac{1}{6}t^3-t^2+t\tag{2}
\end{align*}
These polynomials are a specific form of Laguerre polynomials (1), namely $$l_k(t)=(-1)^kL_k^{(-1)}(t)$$

> **Theorem 2.1** in the referred paper states: Given nonnegative integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, the number of $k$-ary Carlitz words with the letter $i$ used exactly $n_i$ times is
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\left(\prod_{i=1}^kl_{n_i}(t)\right)\,dt\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since we have three characters $r,g,b$ each twice, one character $w$ three times and three characters $y,B,o$ each occurring once, we set
>   \begin{align*}
> &n_1=n_2=n_3=2,\\
> &n_4=3,\\
> &n_5=n_6=n_7=1
> \end{align*}
>
> We apply theorem 2.1. and obtain using (2) and (3) and with some help of Wolfram Alpha
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^\infty&e^{-t}\left(\prod_{i=1}^7l_{n_i}(t)\right)\,dt\\
> &=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\left(l_2(t)\right)^3l_3(t)\left(l_1(t)\right)^3\,dt\\
> &=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-t\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{6}t^3-t^2+t\right)t^3\,dt\\
> &=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{48}t^{12}-\frac{1}{4}t^{11}+\frac{9}{8}t^{10}
> -\frac{29}{12}t^9+\frac{5}{2}t^8-t^7\right)\,dt\\
> &=3301200
> \end{align*}

Comment: Great! This problem seems painfully ad hoc, and I am very pleased to see that there is an analytic solution.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: I agree! It was also great for me to see the combinatorial power of these polynomials. Another powerful method the *cluster method* by Goulden-Jackson could also be applied here (with somewhat more effort). It is presented in *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824587/how-many-words-of-length-n-can-we-make-from-0-1-2-if-2s-cannot-be-conse/1826042#1826042)*.

Comment: I went down the proverbial rabbit hole, fully knowing that I was getting in trouble, but the pain of not getting anywhere certainly gave me an appreciation for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

This question is equivalent to

> "In how many different ways can we arrange letters of the word
>   AABBCCDDDEFG such that no two adjacent letters are alike?"

I have been doing many such questions in past. This [tool](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php) was very useful. Following is the result obtained from this tool.
[see generated question $24$. Thought of retying it here. but as i said in my comment, it is very long and pasting the screenshot here]

> [image]

Comment: Good work! (+1) I've added an answer which confirms your result.